# Listing Azure VMs in multiple subscription under one directory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I have multiple subscriptions and few VMs in each subscription. I am using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` library to list all VMs.

I used below cli command to create authentication file.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth > my.azureauth
```

using the authentication file, I am trying to get all subscription as below

```
var azure = Azure.Authenticate(file).WithDefaultSubscription();
var subs = azure.Subscriptions.List();
```

It seems authentication file generated using command can access only one subscription.

Here is the documentation for command

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create

How can I create an authentication file to access all subscriptions and VMs in each subscription?

Comment: It created a service principal in the directory. You should be able to go to each subscription's Access Control (IAM) tab and give the service principal a role on the missing subscriptions.

Comment: where can I see the service principal?

Comment: If you go to Azure portal, click Azure Active Directory on the left. Then go to Enterprise applications (it's really service principals). It should be somewhere in the list. I'm not sure what the names of the SPs that that generates are :/ Change the filter to All applications if you can't find it.

Comment: You might have some id for the SP in that auth file, you could try finding it with that as well.

Comment: Okay, I tested it out, I'll write up an answer in a moment :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. the application is not under Enterprise Application but in App registrations. I tried to use cli command but it is giving me error "Bad request". Adding SP to subscriptions works.

Comment: Ah it should be under both. The service principal is what gets the permissions after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the command creates a service principal in your Azure AD.
The client id for the principal is found in the file.
You can use it to find the service principal:

1. Go to portal.azure.com
2. Open **Azure Active Directory** from the left
3. Open **Enterprise applications**
4. Enter the client id in the search bar for the enterprise app list
5. You should now find the service principal

For me the service principal is called "azure-cli-2019-03-22-20-05-32".

You can then go to the other subscriptions' Access Control (IAM) tab, and add this SP as a Contributor on them as well.
Just enter the name or client id of the SP in the search when selecting the target of the role.

You can also make the assignments via the CLI:

```
az role assignment create --assignee "your-sp-client-id" --role "Contributor" --scope "/subscriptions/your-subscription-id-here"
```